# Can you use google tag manager to implement custom animations in a mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, google-tag-manager

I was wondering whether it's possible to use google tag manager to implement custom app UX or UI without having to push a new version of an app?

I see that you can use GTM to add tracking code without re-deploying, but can you say push a survey pop-up action from a GTM container, provided it integrates into the rest of the code and there is internet access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can imagine 2 ways you can do it with GTM:

- Use [value collection](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/#get): this is like a list of values that you set in GTM and can be downloaded in your app. Upon getting these values, app can decide what to do during runtime.
  E.g.: `{'transition': 'slide'}`
- Use [custom function call tag](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v3/#function-call-tag): you specify a tag, with trigger rules of course, and the tag type is 'Function Call', where you specify name of function and list of arguments for it. This is like a remote function call. (The link I provide is guide for v3. For some reason they remove it in v4, but it's available in Google Play Services sample in your SDK directory).